# Can't use Android's PhotoViewActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

In Android SDK there is a class called `PhotoViewActivity`. I can navigate to it and view its source code in Android Studio.

The class is public.

Yet when I try to use it it, the IDE stubbornly claims it doesn't know what I'm talking about.

```
public class MyPhotoViewActivity extends com.android.ex.photo.PhotoViewActivity {
   // doesn't compile, can't find the base class
}
```

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 3):

> In Android SDK there is a class called PhotoViewActivity.

No, there is not. You can tell that by looking at [the JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) and seeing that the SDK contains precisely zero classes in the `com.android.ex` series of packages.

The Android source code contains many things that are not part of the Android SDK, just as I am sure that the Windows source code contains many things that are not part of any Windows SDK.

> How do I make it work?

You copy [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/photoviewer/) and everything that it depends upon into your project, adhering to the terms of the relevant licenses (probably just Apache License 2.0, but I haven't examined everything in there).